# Using pivot tables with additional relation

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

In my Laravel application I have a **Centre** that can have **Document Types** and **Documents**. These document types are essentially a list of document types a centre must have and include things like PAT Test.

Here are the relations:

- Many Centres can have many Document types, through a pivot table called centre_document_types
- A centre can have many documents uploaded to it

The point is that for each document type defined, you must upload a corresponding document.

To make it so you can upload a document for each document type by centre I added an additional column to said pivot table:

```
$table->id();
$table->integer('centre_id')->unsigned();
$table->integer('document_type_id')->unsigned();
$table->integer('document_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
```

So if centre 1 had document type 1, you'd upload a document and pass this document id into the pivot table, then you'd say centre 1 has a document attached for document type 1.

This works but am I using a pivot table correctly, I'm literally adding a 1 to 1 relation from a pivot table to a normal table.

Is this bad practise?

Comment: So the same document can belong to multiple types, depending on which centre uploads it?

Comment: Yes, because for some odd reason a Centre can have multiple of a certain document type, it genuinely baffles me also.

Comment: In that case, while ordinarily a bit odd, the above seems reasonable in this instance